# Unpack signed int32 little-endian in PHP

Tags: php, unpack, endianness, int32

I have a binary file that I'm trying to parse. A little part of the file has a set of coordinates (latitude and longitude). A small example could be as follow:

```
$data = "64DA7300 0CD5DFFF";
```

And I'm trying to see the integers but I have no luck yet.

```
$header = unpack("ilatitud/ilongitude", $data);
print_r($header);
```

I know the correct numbers should be: `(7592548, -2108148)`, however the results are `1094988854, 808465207`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is it ADS-B coordinates? If I remember correct they need more than just a normal hex -> binary conversion

Comment: They are just GPS coordinates, the result needs to be divided by 65536 to get the exact coordinate. However, my problem is the conversion.. :/

Comment: `$data = "64DA7300 0CD5DFFF";` thats not in binary.

Comment: @tkausl Yes... Your point is? If you are refering to my comment on binary you could figure out how ADS-B GPS works. It's the stuff airplanes send out to ground telling them where they are. The stuff that makes flightradar work. Since full sized GPS signals was too large for airplanes they compressed it hex -> binary -> decimal to get the coordinates.

Comment: My point is, you're trying to unpack a binary little-endian int from a string which contains the int as ascii-hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data = "64DA7300 0CD5DFFF";
```

Your data is not in binary, it is hex-encoded ascii. Make it binary first:

```
$data = hex2bin(str_replace(" ", "", $data));
```

then your unpack will work.

[Example](https://eval.in/834136)